# Password Encoder Match not working Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am creating the Spring Boot application login with hash password.without set hash password login working successfully.with hash password set getting error while writing the code.

```
passwordEncoder.matches(loginDTO.getEmail())
```

**it indicate the error was**

```
'matches(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.String)' in 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'
```

what i tried so far i attached the full code below.

**LoginDTO.java**

```
package com.example.Registation.Dto;

public class LoginDTO {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public LoginDTO() {
    }

    public LoginDTO(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginDTO{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/login")
    public String loginEmployee(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO)
    {
        String email = employeeService.loginEmployee(loginDTO);
        return email;
    }
```

**Employee Service**

```
public interface EmployeeService {
  

    String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO);
}
```

**EmployeeRepo**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer>
{
      Optional<Employee> findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);

}
```

**EmployeeIMPL**

```
    @Override
public String  loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    CharSequence password = loginDTO.getPassword();
    String encodedPassword = loginDTO.getPassword(); // assume this is the encoded password from the database

    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.matches(password,encodedPassword));

    if (employee.isPresent()) {
        return "Login Success for " + employee.get();
    } else {
        return "Login Fail";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I doubt that your password is the email address. Also your find is wrong you should only login by username. It is wrong al together as Spring Security should handle the login and password validation. You are basically using the encoder wrong and working around Spring Security (stop doing both).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```java
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

//PasswordEncoder bean
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

//check password
if (passwordEncoder.matches(changePasswordRequest.getOldPassword(), user.getPassword())){
    
}
```

Both password type is `String`.
OldPassword and Password type is `String`.

Comment: Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.matches(password,encodedPassword));    is this cannot do it

Comment: can we connect via anydesk

Comment: I fixed your issue

Comment: ya thanks i will give the id waut

Comment: got the anydesk id

Comment: give the email id please

Comment: thanks for you kind help sir. best spring boot programmer thanks.god bless you